# npx create-react-app does not proceed further and stops at "installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx, npm-check-updates

I tried to run it again but still the same issue.

I am using:
**node : v14.0, 
npm: 6.14.4**

Below is the screenshot of the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoN8r.png)

Answer (score 0):

try running `npm install -g create-react-app` first and then `create-react-app my-app`